# What is the difference between mesos-slave and mesos-agent

Tags: mesos

There are some samples using mesos-slave in their tutorials.
What is the difference between mesos-slave and mesos-agent? Which one is preferred?

Answer (score 2):

Slave is deprecated and **agent is preferred**. There is no semantic difference between them.

> TL;DR - Computers sharing work should be a good thing. Using the language of human bondage and suffering is inappropriate in this context. It also has the potential to alienate users and community members.
> [MESOS-1478](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-1478)

With release of Mesos 1.0 they decided to rename slave to agent. For the same reson as it [was done before in Django](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22667) ([pull request](https://github.com/django/django/pull/2692))

For backward compatibility they decided to leave with two versions `slave` and `agent`.